# Is it possible to put label textbox button with tabbed activity? Being specific i have added hand drawn design photo

Tags: android, button, textbox, label, android-tabbed-activity

[Design Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN1Ff.jpg)

it shows the layout of app i am building Electricity Bill view app, in which there is tabbed activity on top of it there is textbox button. In textbox user will enter Consumer No when user clicks button then he/she is forwarded to another activity(another page) of app. which shows last billed and last payment details and have  one plus symbol like button. when user clicks on it he/she have two other option one to update mobile number and other to get E-bill.

I made this layout with help of TabLayout from Containers upon this there is one button to GetDetails of Consumer Bill provided that we will get this by Consumer number from TextBox entered by End User. Constraint Layout is used in whole layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="280dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_GetDetails">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/history" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bookmark" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_to_ugvcl_vij_bill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/find_details_by_consumer_number"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_GetDetails"
        android:layout_width="320sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="@string/get_details"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEditText" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="320sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:bufferType="normal"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/consumer_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_GetDetails"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now what i want to do is when user clicks GetDetails Button then in Another Activity or Another Page of Application itself it should open/show some of Consumer Details like his/her name followed by his/her corresponding Consumer number. It should not fire intent to open this in any installed web browser.

I coded for opening this in web browser is...

```
package com.example.tabbedlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_GetDetails);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent IntViewBill = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                IntViewBill.setData(Uri.parse("http://ugvcl.info/UGBILL/"));
                startActivity(IntViewBill);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and works fine....

But as i mentioned earlier i want it to open in app itself.

One more thing,

there is a scenario like web page "http://ugvcl.info/UGBILL/" uses Captcha Code(Image of Written TextNumber together) to be Entered first by End User to get details of Consumer Bill.

captcha code looks like this [Captcha code changes everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCcPb.png)

How can we handle that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made this layout with help of TabLayout from Containers upon this there is one button to GetDetails of Consumer Bill provided that we will get this by Consumer number from TextBox entered by End User. Constraint Layout is used in whole layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="280dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_GetDetails">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/history" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bookmark" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_to_ugvcl_vij_bill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/find_details_by_consumer_number"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_GetDetails"
        android:layout_width="320sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="@string/get_details"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEditText" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="320sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:bufferType="normal"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/consumer_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_GetDetails"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In short you can use TabLayout or some margin properties to achieve this type of Layout.